# Laravel's the composer.lock file is not updated on docker/ docker-compose

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, composer-php

I am working on a Laravel project. I am using docker-compose/ docker as my development environment.

This is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  apache:
    container_name: myaneat_apache
    image: webdevops/apache:ubuntu-16.04
    environment:
      WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/public
      WEB_ALIAS_DOMAIN: myan.localhost
      WEB_PHP_SOCKET: php-fpm:9000
    volumes: # Only shared dirs to apache (to be served)
      - ./public:/var/www/public:cached
      - ./storage:/var/www/storage:cached
    networks:
      - myaneat-network
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
  php-fpm:
    container_name: myaneat_php
    image: jguyomard/laravel-php:7.3
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
      - ./ci:/var/www/ci:cached
      - ./vendor:/var/www/vendor:delegated
      - ./storage:/var/www/storage:delegated
      - ./node_modules:/var/www/node_modules:cached
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh:cached
      - ./composer.json:/var/www/composer.json
      - ./composer.json:/var/www/composer.lock
      - ~/.composer/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
    networks:
      - myaneat-network
  db:
    container_name: myaneat_db
    image: mariadb:10.2
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: myan
      MYSQL_USER: myan
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - myaneat-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - myaneat-network
    ports:
      - "33060:3306"
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: myaneat_es
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.1
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - es-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - myaneat-network
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.5.1
    container_name: myaneat_kibana
    environment:
      - ./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - myaneat-network
networks:
  myaneat-network:
    driver: "bridge"
volumes:
  myaneat-data:
    driver: "local"
  es-data:
    driver: "local"
```

I am installing a new package running the following command.

```
docker-compose exec php-fpm composer require calebporzio/sushi
```

But only the composer.json is updated but not composer.lock. Also, the package is not downloaded into the vendor folder either. I was working before. Just out of the blue, this happens.

I tried the following:

```
docker-compose exec php-fpm composer clearcache
docker-compose exec php-fpm composer clear-cache
docker-compose exec php-fpm composer dump-autoload
docker-compose exec php-fpm composer update --lock
```

What is the possible root cause? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try run update specific to the lock:

```
docker-compose exec php-fpm composer update --lock
```

This flag is documented [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md)

As for the updating of `.lock` file, you may find info about it [here](https://blog.engineyard.com/composer-its-all-about-the-lock-file), You're interesting in the last clause.

> Running composer update will:
>
> 1. Check composer.json
> 2. Determine the latest versions to install based on your version specs
> 3. Install the latest versions
> 4. Update composer.lock to reflect the latest versions installed

Comment: updating lock seems to be working now. I don't why it did not work in the first place. I tried a couple of other commands too like clearing the cache before updating lock file. But whenever I install a new package, I have to manually run "docker-compose exec php-fpm composer update --lock".